# Dagger2: return not singleton object from singleton component

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

how can I return not singleton objects from a `@Singleton` component?

For example I have:

`ApplicationComponent.kt`

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ApplicationModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent() {
    fun database(): Database
    fun model(): Model
}
```

`Model.kt`

```
class Model @Inject constructor()
```

What I want is to return a different instance of `Model` every time, conversely to `Database` which will be a singleton, and been provided by `ApplicationModule.kt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you provide your `Model` as

```
@Singleton
class Model @Inject constructor()
```

or as

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideModel() = Model()
```

it will be a singleton.

If you don't annotate any provider with `@Singleton`, `@Reusable` or any other scope, you will always create a new instance.